# How to change color of div element depending on color of the block with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 blocks for user to choose from and they should be interactive. The block changes the color and the vertical line color should be changed to opposite. I wonder if I could make it right in the same code snippet which does the color change of the code block, because previously I made it, but with another for loop and it's not the fastest way.

```js
let vanOption = document.getElementsByClassName("van-quote-option");
let quoteVl = document.getElementById("option-vl");

// Van option selection

for (var x = 0; x < vanOption.length; x++) {
  vanOption[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var currentOption = document.getElementsByClassName("option-active");
  if (currentOption.length > 0) { 
    currentOption[0].className = currentOption[0].className.replace(" option-active", "");
  }  
  this.className += " option-active";
  });
}
```

```css
.van-quote-option {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 25px 165px 20px 165px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.option-active {
    background-color: #18A063;
    color: #fff;
}

.quote-vl {
    border-left: 2px solid #13985C;
    height: 116px;
}

.quote-vl-active {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 116px;
}

.quote-icon {
    margin: 25px 0 0 35px;
}

.quote-van-icon {
    font-size: 49px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    color: #18A063;
}

.quote-car-icon {
    font-size: 49px;
    padding: 9px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    color: #18A063;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.quote-bicycle-icon {
    font-size: 49px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    color: #18A063;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.quote-p {
    text-align: left;
}

.quote-p-van {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.bicycle-quote-vl,
.car-quote-vl {
    height: 124px;
}

.quote-price {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.quote-price-van {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.van-send-price,
.car-send-price,
.bicycle-send-price {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.van-send-price::before,
.car-send-price::before,
.bicycle-send-price::before {
    content: "\00A3";
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-options">
        <div class="van-quote-option option-active">
          <div class="quote-icon quote-icon-1">
            <i class="fas fa-truck quote-van-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="quote-p-van">
            <div class="quote-p-1">Sending 1 or 2 items (with van)</div>
            <br />
            <div class="quote-p-2">
              We'll take a maximum of 2 items for you<br />
              to deliver immediately at any location.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="quote-vl quote-vl-active"></div>
          <div class="quote-price-van">
            <span class="van-send-price" id="van-deliver-price">14</span><br />
            For a max.<br />
            of 2 items.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="van-quote-option">
          <div class="quote-icon quote-icon-1">
            <i class="fas fa-truck quote-van-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="quote-p-van">
            <div class="quote-p-1">Hire a van</div>
            <br />
            <div class="quote-p-2">
              We'll take a maximum of 2 items for you<br />
              to deliver immediately at any location.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="quote-vl"></div>
          <div class="quote-price-van">
            <span class="van-send-price" id="van-deliver-price">38</span><br />
            Hire a van,<br />
            &#8734; items
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with css.
You don't really need the `quote-vl-active` class. Remove it.
You can refer to the vertical line when it's active using `option-active` since it's the child of that element.

```
.option-active > .quote-vl {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
    height: 116px;
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29r1v0Lo/

Answer (score 0):

might want to use `onclick` vs. adding listeners as well.

Here is a jsfiddle of it a bit cleaner and with the vert bar having the opposite color: https://jsfiddle.net/7L0uzkxj/

You can just have the CSS control the vert bar:

```
.quote-vl {
    border-left: 2px solid green;
    height: 116px;
}
.option-active .quote-vl {
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    height: 116px;
}
```

You can then clean up the JS to look like this:

```
function triggerMe(evt) {
  let vanOption = document.getElementsByClassName("van-quote-option");
  [...vanOption].forEach(x => {
    if (x.classList.contains('option-active')) {
      x.classList.remove('option-active');
    }
  })
  evt.classList.toggle('option-active');
}
```